# Is it possible to find which elasticsearch shard(s) a document is on?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, sharding

I'm having trouble debugging a parent child relationship query.  I'd like to know ways of debugging the issue, rather than simply posting my mapping, data, query, and asking what's wrong (but I reserve the right to do so eventually!).

To that end, a start would be checking if my children and associated parent are on the same shard.  I don't trust my mapping, and I don't want to calculate which shard the documents are theoretically on, using *shard = hash(routing) % number_of_primary_shards*.  I want a query that returns a definite answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your query , you can enable explain flag and it will tell you where each of the documents are from which shard and node.
You can find a sample query as follows -

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Along with docID , index name and type name , it will also emit node ID and shard ID.

You can find samples on usage of explain API [here](https://qbox.io/blog/computing-distance-from-a-reference-point-with-script-fields-and-the-explain-api).

Comment: Thanks, the `explain` is what I was looking for.  Your json is consistent with the elasticsearch documentation - no route, endpoint, querystring, verb - as a n00b this drives me nuts!  I’ve figured them out, but not before deleting documents.  Presumably these things are no-brainers at your level of experience.  This is what I’m using: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=_id:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&explain&pretty'`

Answer (score 1):

To debug this you don't have to check shard and node identifiers at all.

All you have to do is make sure that `_parent` and/or `_routing` fields of the child documents match the `id` of the parent document. Use `/_search?pretty&fields=_parent,_routing&_source=true` to show these fields.

To find docs with a specific `_routing` or `_parent` id just use `/_search?pretty&fields=_parent,_routing&_source=true&q=id:123 OR _routing:123 OR _parent:123` This will find parent docs *and* child docs.

Comment: Alas, everything looks fine to me which is why I’m trying to check anything else that I can.  The child has a _routing field with the parent’s _id.  The child _source has a parentid field with the parent’s _id.  The index mapping has the child defined with a _parent type, routing required, and path set to parentid as in the child _source.  The has_parent query worked in a previous version of elasticsearch, but is now failing in 1.4.4.  I’ll post this as a new question in a couple of hours, and notify you.  I’m missing compilers and debuggers.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would help if you posted mapping & query for this.

Comment: In a separate question agreed, but here my interest was: _I'd like to know ways of debugging the issue, rather than simply posting my mapping..._